# Shadcn dialog became blurred

Tags: reactjs, shadcnui

I have no idea why sometimes my shadcn dialog component became blurred as below
[image]

When I switch the `switch` component off then its unblurred. So it seems that changing the size of dialog make it blurred. How to avoid that?Below unblurred one:

[image]

Comment: can you please provide full screen screenshot?